# What is the need for Euler substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration

We use Euler substitution to find closed forms for integrals which have $\sqrt{ax^2 + bx + c}$ in it.

We can always complete the square to get $\displaystyle \sqrt{ax^2 + bx + c}= \sqrt{(x - d)^2 \pm e} = \sqrt{e} \sqrt{\left({x-d\over \sqrt{e}}\right)^2 \pm 1}$

Now we can substitute $\tan \theta$ or $\sec \theta$ respectively,  $=\left({x-d\over \sqrt{e}}\right)$ depending on the sign of $1$. Then we can get rid of pesky root. No need for cumbersome Euler substitutions that is more prone to error making than any other method I know.

Am I wrong ? is there a quadratic under root that cannot be completed by square ?

Comment: How do we know that $\sqrt{ax^2 + bx + c}$ can we written as $\sqrt{(x-d)^2 \pm e}$ ?

Comment: @Leth Completing the square.

Comment: Seems to assume $a=1$